# How can I merge rows in np matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a numpy matrix that has 2 rows and N columns, e.g. (if `N=4`):

```
[[ 1  3  5   7]
 [ 2  4  6   8]]
```

The goal is create a string `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`.

- Merge the rows such that the elements from the first row have the even (1, 3, ..., N - 1) positions (the index starts from 1) and the elements from the second row have the odd positions (2, 4, ..., N).

The following code works but it isn't really nice:

```
    xs = []
    for i in range(number_of_cols):
        xs.append(nums.item(0, i))
    ys = []
    for i in range(number_of_cols):
        ys.append(nums.item(1, i))
    nums_str = ""
    for i in range(number_of_cols):
        nums_str += '{},{},'.format(xs[i], ys[i])
```

- Join the result list with a comma as a delimiter (`row.join(',')`)

How can I merge the rows using built in functions (or just in a more elegant way overall)?

Comment: You probably need to use [`flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `F` order when flattening (or ravel):

```
In [279]: arr = np.array([[1,3,5,7],[2,4,6,8]])                                           
In [280]: arr                                                                             
Out[280]: 
array([[1, 3, 5, 7],
       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
In [281]: arr.ravel(order='F')                                                            
Out[281]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining rows can be done this way :

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> np.hstack([a[i,:] for i in range(a.shape[0])])
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Then it's simple to convert this array into string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
out_str = ','.join(nums.T.ravel().astype('str'))
```

We are first transposing the array with `.T`, then flattening it with `.ravel()`, then converting each element from `int` to `str`, and then applying `','.join() to combine all the str elements

**Trying it out:**

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.array([[1,3,5,7],[2,4,6,8]])
out_str = ','.join(nums.T.ravel().astype('str'))
print (out_str)
```

**Result:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```